# Frequently run into exceptions from MongoDB perl driver

Tags: perl, mongodb

The web application is running but in my log error frequently run into this exceptions

```
can't get db response, not connected at ../MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 160.

invalid header received at ../MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 160.

can't locate object method "new" via package "MongoDB::Timestamp" at ../MongoDB/Collection.pm line 370.
```

Perl Driver

- [MongoDB-0.702.2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/) ,

MongoDB server "version 2.4.8"

- 1 master
- 2 replication

MongoDB server status connection server sometime reach the limit connection

```
"connections" : {
        "current" : 20000,
        "available" : 0,
        "totalCreated" : NumberLong(73428104)
 },
```

Here my code for get connection from MongoDB

```
sub get_mongodb {
my ($self) = @_;

#master/slave
my $mode    = $self->mode;

#get db name
my $db      = $self->db;

my $obj = $self->{'o_mongodb_' . $mode . '_' . $db};

unless($obj) {
    my %opt;

    #result get_con
    #{
    #    'db'    => 'mongo',
    #    'host'  => [
    #            '10.10.10.1:27017',
    #            '10.10.10.2:27017',
    #            '10.10.10.3:27017'
    #       ]
    #}
    my $con = $self->get_con($db);

    if($mode eq 'master') {
        $opt{find_master} = 1;
    }
    else {
        $opt{find_master} = 0;
    }

    $opt{timeout}       = 50000;
    $opt{query_timeout} = -1;

    my @host    = @{$con->{host}};
    @host       = $self->{t}->util->shuffle(@host);
    $opt{host}  = 'mongodb://' . join(',', @host);

    my @opt = %opt;
    my $client;

    eval { 
        local $SIG{__DIE__}; 
        $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(@opt);
    };

    if(!$@) {
        $obj = $self->{'o_mongodb_' . $mode . '_' . $db} = $client->get_database($con->{db});
    }
    else {
        return 0;   
    }
}

if($mode eq 'master') {
    $MongoDB::Cursor::slave_okay = 0;
}
else {
    $MongoDB::Cursor::slave_okay = 1;   
}

return $obj;
}
```

Is there something my code is wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: How often does this code get called? Is it being invoked on every request?

Comment: yes every request for query mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly running out of connections. The reason for this is clear from your comment, in that you are making a new connection with every request that results in hitting the database.

One thing you could try is to reduce the [timeout](http://api.mongodb.org/perl/current/MongoDB/Connection.html#timeout) value. This defaults to `20000ms` and you are actually setting that higher. As a result connections are "hanging around", and with a busy server that is going to build up quickly.

A better strategy is to implement connection pooling. There is no default feature in the Perl driver, but there is a [guide on the site](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/notes-on-pooling-for-mongodb-drivers/) that can give you some guidance on how to implement.

As an alternate to building that yourself you might want to look into [MongoDBx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~idoperel/MongoDBx-Class-1.030002/lib/MongoDBx/Class.pm), which does have a connection pooling strategy.

The basic premise is that you do **not** want to be establishing a new connection for every request, but instead re-use from an available pool, of a set number, that will not allow your app to exhaust the available connections. You will also find that operation times are significantly faster, without the overhead of establishing a connection every time.

Comment: I tried using MongoDBX::Class, the log error became this, Attempt to reload MongoDB/Timestamp.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 2211) line 2.

Comment: @tdhong Perhaps you can raise that in **another question** here or even submit a bug report to the author. This is not my area of expertise as I do not use it myself. My **answer** is about the problem you are having **here**, which is you have to get away from creating a new connection on every request. I gave you that information and some **suggestions** on strategies to help you do that. That seems to have helped you to start looking at how you can fix these issues in your application. So go ahead and ask another question, and please appreciate the guidance that was given.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too , check mongodb.log  if you have many connection that don't close

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PERL-264